# How to arbitrarily extract a specific subset of images from a dataset?

Tags: indexing, extract, dm-script

Recently I'm planning to manipulate a stack of images and the goal is to extract a specific subset of slices from there, for example only even or odd or arbitrary indexes, and then save them into another dataset.

In DM, there are a number of helpful functions in the Volume menu but unfortunately, they cannot really fullfill what I want to do.

I am just wondering whether this idea can be realized via scripting.

Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: I suggest you post you initial code solution on your question. Most SO users will ask you to show that you have put some effort into solving your question by yourself. Besides, it makes helping you with your question a lot easier. Good luck and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is a very good question for starting to use DM script as data analysis tool, so I've put in a more extensive answer than necessary to have a reference for people. The `quick` answer is: All functionality of the *Volume* menu is easily reproducible with very few code lines using the command `SliceN` as described at the bottom of my answer.

Comment: You have a lovely user-image ;c)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can go about it, one of them only suitable for data up to 3D and generally slower than the other, but more flexible. 
As you have been asking for *arbitrary* subsampling, I'm starting with that option, but it is more likely that the second option gives you what you want: *orthogonal, regular* subsampling.

If you are in a hurry, the short answer is: **Use the `SliceN` command.**

---

### 1) Using expressions (arbitrary subsampling)

> Individual pixel positions in an *Image* data (`img`) can be addressed
>   using the notations
>
> - `img[ X, 0 ]` ... for 1D data at position `X`
> - `img[ X, Y ]` ... for 2D data at position `X/Y`
> - `img[ X, Y, Z ]` ... for 3D data at position `X/Y/Z`

Note that even if this addresses a single number, the result is an *expression* of size *1x1* or *1x1x1* and not a scalar number, therefore you **can not** do: `number num = img[10,4]`

However, you can use a little trick to use any of the functions that convert an expression to a single number like f.e. summation. So you **can do**: `number num = sum(img[10,4])`

So how does this relate to your question? Well, in the expressions above, we used scalar values as `X`, `Y` and `Z`, and the resulting expressions were expressions of size *1x1* and *1x1x1*, but

> You can use *expressions* of any size as `X`, `Y`, `Z` in this notations, as long as all of them are *expressions* of *same* size. The resulting addressed data is of this size with values references by the according coordinates.

This will become clearer with the examples below. Starting out with a simple 1D example:

```
image img1D := RealImage( "TestData", 4, 100 )
image coord := RealImage( "Coordinates", 4, 10 )

img1D = 1000 + icol             // Just sum test data
coord = trunc(100*Random())     // random integer 0-99
image subImg :=  img1D[coord,0]

img1D.ShowImage()
coord.ShowImage()
subImg.ShowImage()
```

[image: Example of arbitrary subsampling 1D]

Our testdata (`img1D`) here is just a linear graph from 1000 to 1099 using the `icol` expression which, at each pixel, represents that pixels X coordinate.

The coordinate image (`coord`) is containing random integer values between 0 and 99.

The 'magic' happens in the `subImg`. We use an expression with the `coord` image as X coordinates. That images is of size *10(x1)*, so the outcoming expression is of size *10(x1)* which we assign to the image `subImg` before showing it.

Note, that the *expression* we have built is really just pointing to that data of the image. Instead of showing it as a new image, we could have use that expression to *change* these points in the data instead, using:

`img1D[coord,0] = 0`

[image: Example of setting data by expression]

---

Taking it from here, it is straight forward to extend the example to 2D:

```
image img2D := RealImage( "TestData", 4, 30, 30 )
image coordX := RealImage( "Coordinates X", 4, 10 )
image coordY := RealImage( "Coordinates Y", 4, 10 )

img2D = 10000 + icol + irow * 100
coordX = trunc(30*Random())
coordY = trunc(30*Random())
img2D[coordX,coordY] = 0

coordX.ShowImage()
coordY.ShowImage()
img2D.ShowImage()
```

[image: Example for 2D]

---

...and 3D:

```
image img3D := RealImage( "TestData", 4, 30, 30, 30 )
image coordX := RealImage( "Coordinates X", 4, 10 )
image coordY := RealImage( "Coordinates Y", 4, 10 )
image coordZ := RealImage( "Coordinates Y", 4, 10 )

img3D = 10000 + icol + irow * 100 + iplane * 1000
coordX = trunc(30*Random())
coordY = trunc(30*Random())
coordZ = trunc(30*Random())
img3D[coordX,coordY,coordZ] = 0

coordX.ShowImage()
coordY.ShowImage()
coordZ.ShowImage()
img3D.ShowImage()
```

---

Unfortunately, it ends here.

> You can no longer do this type of addressing in 4D or 5D data, because expression with 4 parameters are already defined to address a rectangle region in 2D data as `img[T,L,B,R]`

---

---

### 2) Using SliceN (orthogonal subsampling)

> Data subsets along the dimension directions of data can be addressed using the command `SliceN` and its simplified variants `Slice1`, `Slice2` and `Slice3`.

The `SliceN` command is maybe one of my favourite commands in the language when dealing with data. It looks intimidating at first, but it is straight forward.

Lets start with its simplified version for 1D extraction, `Slice1`.

> To extract 1D data from any data up to 3D with the `Slice1` command, you need the following (-and these are exactly the 7 parameters used by the command-):
>
> - data source
> - start point in the source
> - sampling direction
> - sampling length
> - sampling step-size
>
> The only thing you need to know on top of that is:
>
> - The start point is *always* defined as a `X,Y,Z` triplet, even if the data source is only 2D or 1D. 
>   `0` is used for the not needed
>     dimensions.
> - Directions are given as dimension index: 0 = X, 1 = Y, 2 = Z
> - Step-size can be negative to indicate opposite directions
> - The specified sampling must be contained within the source data.
>   (You can not 'extrapolate')

So a very simple example of extracting a 1D data of a 3D dataset would be:

```
number sx = 20
number sy = 20
number sz = 20

image img3D := RealImage( "Spectrum Image", 4, sx, sy, sz )
img3D = 5000000 + icol + irow * 100 + iplane * 10000

number px = 5
number py = 7
image spec1D := Slice1( img3D, px,py,0, 2,sz,1 )

ShowImage( img3D )
ShowImage( spec1D )
```

This example showed a quite typical situation in analytical microscopy when dealing with "3D Spectrum Image" data: Extracting a "1D Spectrum" at a specific spatial position.

The example did that for the spatial point `px,py`. Starting at the point at that position (`px,py,0`), it samples along the Z direction (`2`) for all pixels of the data (`sz`) with a step-size of `1`.

Note, that the command again returns an *expression* within the source data, and that you can use this to *set* values as well, just using f.e.:

`Slice1( img3D, px,py,0, 2,sz,1 ) = 0`

---

The extension for 2D and 3D data using the commands `Slice2` and `Slice3` is straight forward. Instead of defining *one* output direction, you define *two* or *three*, respectively. Each with a triplet of numbers: *direction, length, step-size*.

The following example extracts an "image plane" of a "3D Spectrum image":

```
number sx = 20
number sy = 20
number sz = 20

image img3D := RealImage( "Spectrum Image", 4, sx, sy, sz )
img3D = 5000000 + icol + irow * 100 + iplane * 10000

number pz = 3
image plane2D := Slice2( img3D, 0,0,pz, 0,sx,1, 1,sy,1 )

ShowImage( img3D )
ShowImage( plane2D )
```

And the following example "rotates" a 3D image:

```
number sx = 6
number sy = 4
number sz = 3

image img3D := RealImage( "Spectrum Image", 4, sx, sy, sz )
img3D = 1000 + icol + irow * 10 + iplane * 100

image rotated := Slice3( img3D, 0,0,0, 0,sx,1, 2,sz,1, 1,sy,1 )

ShowImage( img3D )
ShowImage( rotated  )
```

---

> You can get all sorts of rotations, mirroring, binning with these
>   commands. If you want the full flexibility to get any expression up to
>   5D from any source data up to 5D, then you need the most versatile
>   `SliceN` command.

It works exactly the same, but you need to specify both the dimensionality of the source data, and the dimensionality of the output expression. Then, the 'starting' point needs to be defined with as many coordinates as the source data dimension suggests, and you need one triplet of specification for each output dimension.

For a source data of `N` dimensions and want an output of `M` dimensions you need: `2 + N + 3*M` parameters.

As an example, lets extract the "plane" at specific spatial position from a "4D Diffraction image" data, which stores a 2D image at each spatial location of a 2D scan:

```
number sx = 9
number sy = 9
number kx = 9
number ky = 9

image img4D := RealImage( "Diffraction Image", 4, sx, sy, kx, ky )
img4D = 50000 + icol + irow * 10 + idimindex(2)*100 + idimindex(3)*1000

number px = 3
number py = 4

image img2D := SliceN( img4D, 4, 2, px,py,0,0, 2,kx,1, 3,ky,1 )

ShowImage( img4D )
ShowImage( img2D )
```

Comment: Hi BmyGuest, many thanks for these useful suggestions. The lovely user image would be helpful to be recognized by the community of microscopist : )

Continuing this discussion, I would like to go further to specify the question. If there is a "large" 3D dataset, say 256 x 256 x 64, and I want to extract only the even indexed slices (slice 0, 2, 4...62). Except for the method of using SliceN to individually extract the slices first and then combining them together afterwards, is there any other efficient command to fit this purpose? Otherwise, the whole process could be very tedious.

Comment: @DMAdventurer Just use `data3D.slice3( 0,0,0, 0,sx,1, 1,sy,1, 2,sz/2,2 )` with sx,sy,sz being the size of of the data3D image.

Comment: That's really a tricky and smart method. By changing the starting point in the z direction, we can then sample either even or odd indexed slices, am I right?

Comment: By the way, would it be possible to sample a more specified set of slices, for example, slice 2, 7, 9, 13...(sort of arbitrary)?

Comment: @DMAdventurer Correct, and by putting it into a loop, (and summing) you can get binning accomplished. The 'Slice' commands are really powerful, that's why I like them so much.

Comment: @DMAdventurer No, non-uniform stepsizes are not supported in the Slice command. BTW, if you think the answer "solves" your question, it would be good to mark it as "accepted".

Comment: Could you kindly tell me how to mark it accepted? I cannot find this option...(sorry I am very new here).

Comment: @DMAdventurer Sure: On the top of each answer/question to the left you see "upvote" and "downvote" arrows to give you judgement of the post. As a qustion author, you will also find a litte "checkmark" icon next to answers, which you can click.